# Outside EU provision of consultancy to EU country, is EU VAT due?

Tags: european-union, vat

I'm self employed in the UK. I work as a sole trader and am not VAT registered.

I have a client in the EU (Belgium) who I'll be doing some consultancy and technical services (e.g. requirements analysis, design, programming) for.

I'm not registered for VAT in the UK, and the work is on the order of €1000-€10000.

It's currently not clear if this will be a B2B or B2C transaction, so I need to understand both cases. The service will be provided from the UK, and is not a 'digital service' - i,e. it is not anything like an automated provision of a digital product and will involve manual human work, done in the UK.

Do I need to charge, collect or pay EU VAT for this?

TIA!

Comment: If you're in the UK, what does EU VAT have to do with you? You might need to collect the UK VAT though, unless they're VAT registered and give you their VAT number.